# How to mobile redirect specific pages on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, mobile

Here is the current code I have placed in the header.php file on our Wordpress site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
  if (screen.width <= 700) {
    window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
  }
 //-->
</script>
```

This issue is, this redirects all pages of our site to the landing page. I only want the 3 of our pages to be redirected. Can I redirect pages to our mobile version by their page id? (I want to avoid using a plugin for this.) If so, how would I write this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done server side and the determination is made by reading the user-agent header. [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) is a PHP library I've had good luck with.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pageName = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); 

if (screen.width <= 700 && (pageName == 'filename1' || pageName == 'filename2' || pageName == 'filename3' ))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the 'filename' the page id or page name or something else?

Comment: That would work if your page has a filename.  If your pages don't have filenames but instead have folder names, you could change the first line to var pageName = location.pathname;